Background color of UITabBar is affected by inner WKWebView
I have created an UIWebView like this:
struct MyUIWebView: UIViewRepresentable {

    let fileName: String
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        return WKWebView()
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ webView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: fileName, withExtension: "html") else { return }
        guard let htmlString = try? String(contentsOf: url, encoding: .utf8) else { return }

        webView.loadHTMLString(htmlString, baseURL: url)
        webView.isOpaque = false
        webView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        webView.scrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    }
}

Then, I place it in a TabView item, like this:
struct HomePage: View {
    @State private var selection = 0

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VStack {
                TabView(selection: $selection) {
                    MyUIWebView(fileName: "index")
                        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                        .tabItem {
                            Image(systemName: "chart.xyaxis.line")
                            Text("Item 1")
                        }
                        .tag(0)
                    
                    Text("Item 2")
                        
                        .font(.system(size: 40, weight: .bold, design: .default))
                        .tabItem {
                            Image(systemName: "square.and.pencil")
                            Text("Item 2")
                        }
                        .tag(1)
                    
                    
                }.accentColor(.white)
                .onAppear() {
                    UITabBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.black
                    UITabBar.appearance().unselectedItemTintColor = .gray
                }
                
            }
        }
        .background(.black)
    }
}

My problem is: when the index.html file is loaded in the WebView, the background color of TabBar is changed. As follow:
Before the html file is loaded, or when I scrolled to the bottom of the website:

After the html file is loaded:

How to keep TabBar background color not to be affected by the WebView?

Does this post help?
